# Hide text from <here> to the end of an <element>

Tags: jquery

If I have a section of content say like this:

```
<div>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <span id="more">Read more...</span>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

How can I hide all the markup that comes after the `<span>` until the closing `</div>`?

I've marked something up in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/6uPnS/), which you can work with.

Thanks

Al

Comment: u want read more facility..right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#more").nextAll("p").hide();
```

if you have more elements than just `<p>`, repeat this function in same way

http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Answer (score 3):

If you're starting out with it showing and want to hide it, probably [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), which collects following siblings matching a selector. Since the `p` elements are siblings of the `span`:

```
$("#more").nextAll("p").hide();
```

I'd also start out with the "more" link hidden, so that people not using JavaScript at all can read the article without this odd link in the middle. :-) So:

```
<div>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <span id="more" style="display: none">Read more...</span>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

and

```
$("#more").show().nextAll("p").hide();
```

Wrapping that up to hook up a handler for showing them again:

```
$("#more")
    .show()
    .click(function() {
        $(this).hide().nextAll("p").show();
    })
    .nextAll("p").hide();
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uPnS/3/)

Answer (score 0):

this one is also very easy and useful **jquery plugin**..

#### http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Id rather not use a plugin if possible.